# How to exit cash while using confidential identities in V2

Tags: corda

I noticed that the change ([Add confidential identity support to cash exit logic #1849](https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/1849/files)) is not in release-V2, any reason why is it not implemented in V2 ([OnLedgerAsset](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V2/finance/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/OnLedgerAsset.kt#L238)) ? I'm using Corda 2.0 and cash using confidential identities cannot be exited properly.

```
net.corda.finance.flows.CashException: Exiting more cash than exists
at net.corda.finance.flows.CashExitFlow.call(CashExitFlow.kt:58)
at net.corda.finance.flows.CashExitFlow.call(CashExitFlow.kt:29)
at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243)
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69)
Caused by: net.corda.core.contracts.InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient balance, missing 2000.00 THB issued by C=UK,L=London,O=Bank1[00]
at net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.OnLedgerAsset$Companion.generateExit(OnLedgerAsset.kt:238)
at net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.OnLedgerAsset.generateExit(OnLedgerAsset.kt:303)
at net.corda.finance.flows.CashExitFlow.call(CashExitFlow.kt:53)
... 17 more
```

Comment: I believe #1849 is a fix for a different issue. Can you post your flow code and the sequence of RPC calls you are making to trigger the exception?

Comment: I replicated the scenario in jUnit per below:

1. Node A starts `CashIssueFlow` USD 2000.00 to himself
2. Node A starts `CashPaymentFlow` USD 1000.00 to Node B with anonymous = true 
3. Node A starts `CashPaymentFlow` USD 1000.00 to Node C
with anonymous = true 
4. Node B sends back USD 1000.00 to Node A
5. Node C sends back USD 1000.00 to Node A
6. Node A starts `CashExitFlow` of USD 2000.00 

Error happens at Step 6.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to replicate it. I'll investigate :)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug. I've reported it here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/2342 and created a JIRA ticket here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-913.